# Unable to create setup EF Core and create migrations in a new .NET Core console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I am attempting to create a simple .NET Core console app that accesses a database through EF Core. No matter what I do I am unable to successfully setup my `Program.cs` to fulfill whatever is needed. I keep getting the error below when trying to run migrations:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> The entry point exited without ever building an IHost. Unable to
> create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve
> service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[TestConsoleApp.ApplicationDbContext]'
> while attempting to activate 'TestConsoleApp.ApplicationDbContext'.'
> was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different
> patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Here are the exact steps I am doing (along w/ my exact code) if anyone wants to try and reproduce. Please note this all works perfectly fine when creating a Web API from scratch using `dotnet new webapi`.

I am running the following command to create a new .NET Core 8 console app:

```
dotnet new console -n ConsoleApp
```

I installed the following NuGet packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.2" />
```

I then create an `Entities` folder and add a simple `Product.cs` entity to it.

I then create a `Data` folder and add an `ApplicationDbContext` to it that looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
{
    public
```

ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
}

```
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my `Program.cs` I am doing the following:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

// Add DbContext configuration
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlite("Data Source=App.db");
});

// Build the service provider
using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
    // Resolve the DbContext from the service provider
    var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
}
```

I then attempt to run the following command from the root of my project:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -o Data/Migrations
```

The error message suggests that the application is unable to build an instance of the `IHost` or `IWebHost`. Maybe what I am doing in the `Program.cs` of the console app does not fulfill this?

I removed everything from Program.cs and added the following to the DbContext directly:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=MyApp.db");
}
```

The migrations actually create now and things appear to be working. However, I am still getting a yellow warning/error saying: "An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The entry point exited without ever building an IHost."

If I add Console.ReadLine(); to Program.cs when calling the dotnet ef add migrations command the migrations are created, the console app stays running fine, then when I close it using ctrl+c the same yellow warning/error appears. I am going to assume it is a harmless error.

I really wanted to be able to have my DbContext sit in a central location so a WebAPI or a ConsoleApp could access it. The problem here is that the WebAPI can fulfill the context options injection, but the console app can't.

Comment: Since a **console app** has nothing to do with the ASP.NET Core web stack, I changed your mentions of **ASP.NET Core** to just **.NET Core**

Comment: The host is responsible for app startup and lifetime management. you just set up the DI but how will the app use it at runtime? by using IHost. ``WebApi`` works because at some point in ``Program.cs`` there is ``app.Run()`` that is calling Host to run.

Comment: You should implement generic host in your console app. That should fix your issue - https://dfederm.com/building-a-console-app-with-.net-generic-host/

Comment: @J.Memisevic Thank you so much! This was exactly what needed to be done. I must be the only one who has tried to setup a console app in this way. Every other resource was using the OnConfiguring approach. If you want to write up an answer I will mark it as the correct one and hopefully this post can help someone else.

Comment: Hi @BlakeRivell , I'm glad that I could help. Team work makes a dream work. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `.Net core` console app to work with `Entity Framework Core` console app needs to work with generic host from `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`.

Example on how to implement generic host can be found on this blog [post](https://dfederm.com/building-a-console-app-with-.net-generic-host/) by David Federman